# Can I use a Verizon iPhone 5 on T-Mobile’s LTE network?

Tags: iphone

I'm thinking of switching to T-Mobile and I am waiting for the 6 to come out. I don't want to switch, have to buy a 5s use it for a week and then turn around and buy the 6. So will the Verizon iPhone 5 work on T-Mobile’s LTE HSPA+?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only HSPA 21mbps in select areas, you will atleast have 2g coverage. LTE will not work though